# parse text between b(bold) tag

Tags: php, parsing

i am trying to log into my hulkshare account, and then return my account information. The curl login is workfine but i dnt think my parsing is working because when i use var_dump($tag) it returns array(0) { }

I am trying to parse the points in my account and here is the code fro the table located between a bold tag < b>6302.00 downloads< /b>

```
<div id="content-wrap">
<div id="wrap-in">
<br>
<table>
<tbody><tr><td>Username:</td><td><b></b></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>You have collected:</td><td><b>6302.00 downloads</b></td><td><input type="button" class="btn2" value="Convert downloads" onclick="document.location='?op=convert_points'"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Used space:</td><td><b>354.0 of 200000 Mb</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>My published files link:</td><td colspan="2"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></td></tr>
<tr><td>My affiliate link:</td><td colspan="2"><a href=""></a><br><small>New user will get 10 downloads</small></td></tr>
</tbody></table>

$cookiefile = '/temp/cookies.txt';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.hulkshare.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'op=login&redirect=&login=XXXXXX&password=XXXXX');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://hulkshare.com/?op=my_account');
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//parse
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
libxml_use_internal_errors(FALSE);
$tag = $xml->xpath("/table/tbody/tr/tb/b");

var_dump($tag);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple things you want to extract from a page, then it's advisable to use a library like phpQuery or QueryPath wich allows for a much simplified:

```
foreach (qp($html)->find("b") as $b)  print $b->text();
```

But in your case you should head straight for text extraction. You have a very clear pattern and a page that is unlikely to change a lot. Use a regex. HTML tags make nice anchors, but you actually only had to look for the decimals before "download":

```
preg_match('#<b>([\d.]+) downloads#i', $html, $match);
$downloads = $match[1];
```

Comment: @jennifer Note that third party libraries like QueryPath and phpQuery might be more conventient to use, but they are not necessary. PHP also has native extensions to parse HTML with DOM and XMLReader.